# AngularJS: Need to resolve a bug of empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a subscription feature which is open through checking a radio box. When open inside this section I have 2 radio buttons for subscribe the period weekly or monthly and below an item. When I pressing save the state of this period have to be saved for one item I have from the server. You can check the screenshot to see the [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GwOf.png). Anyway, there is no save because the array result empty and that item is not in that array. My problem is I see the item below but somehow I'm not pushing it into the array with the period selected from radio buttons. I would like to receive help to understand why of that and what I should modify to make it works properly.

Please check the code I'm sharing controller and view:

```
searchApp.controller('UserSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$rootScope', 'aiStorage', 'userConfig', 'UserSettingsService', 'WebsiteSource', 'AnalyticsEmailService', 'toaster', '$translate', '$filter', 'ngTableParams',
function($scope, $q, $rootScope, store, userConfig, UserSettingsService, WebsiteSource, AnalyticsEmailService, toaster, $translate, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.availableLanguages = {
            da: 'Dansk',
            en: 'English',
            sv: 'Svensk'
        }
        window.scope = $scope
        $scope.userInfo = store.get('user')
        $scope.loadingAction = false
        $scope.selectFlag = false
        $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = []
        $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
        $scope.analyticsEmailSettings = {}
        $scope.engines = angular.copy(WebsiteSource.sites)
        AnalyticsEmailService.getUserSubscription().then(
            function success(response) {
                $scope.loadingAction = false
                $scope.subscription = response
                console.log('response.data', response.data)
                $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(response.data)
                getUnselectedEngines()
                $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed = (response.data.length > 0)
            },
            function error() {})
    }

    function populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(data) {
        console.log('data', data)
        var subscriptionEngines = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var subscription = data[i]
            var engine = $scope.engines.filter(function(x) {
                if (x.id === subscription.engine) {
                    var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(x)
                    $scope.engines[index].type = subscription.type
                }

                return x.id === subscription.engine
            })[0]
            console.log('engine', engine)
            if (engine) subscription.name = engine.name

            subscriptionEngines.push(subscription)
        }
        console.log('subscriptionEngines', subscriptionEngines)
        if (subscriptionEngines.length == 0) {
            $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription = 'WeeklyAnalytics'
        } else {
            $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription = subscriptionEngines[0].type
        }
        return subscriptionEngines
    }

    // Save for all always the user have to press the save button if wants save no auto save as it is now
    $scope.save = function() {
            $scope.loadingAction = true
            if ($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed) {
                AnalyticsEmailService.updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer, function success(response) {}, function error() {})
            } else {
                $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription = 'WeeklyAnalytics'
                $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = []
                AnalyticsEmailService.updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer, function success(response) {}, function error() {})
            }
            UserSettingsService.save({
                userId: $scope.userInfo.id
            }, $scope.userInfo, function() {
                $scope.loadingAction = false
                userConfig.setCurrentUserConfig($scope.userInfo)
                userConfig.setUserLocale()
                store.set('user', $scope.userInfo)
                toaster.pop({
                    type: 'success',
                    body: $translate.instant('notifications_user_settings_changed_success')
                })
            }, function() {})
            $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
        }
        // removeSelectedEngines
    getUnselectedEngines = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.engines.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.filter(function(x) {
                    return x.engine === $scope.engines[i].id
                }).length == 0)
                $scope.engines[i].type = ''
        }
    }

    // @todo: consider referring by array key instead of engineId
    function updatesubscriptions(engineId, subscriptionType) {
        var engine
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine == engineId) {
                engine = $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i]
            }
        }

        engine.type = subscriptionType
        engine.engine = engineId
    }

    $scope.updateSubscriptionType = function(engine) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
            updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine, $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription)
        }
    }

    $scope.addSubscribedEngine = function(engine) {
        $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
        engine.type = $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription

        $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.push({
            type: engine.type,
            engine: engine.id,
            name: engine.name
        })
    }

    $scope.selectFirstUnsubscribedEngine = function() {
        var filtered
        filtered = $scope.engines.filter(function(x) {
            return x.type == ''
        })

        filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, 'name')

        $scope.engine.current = filtered.length ? filtered[0] : null
    }

    $scope.removeSubscribedEngine = function(engine) {
        engine.type = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine == engine.id) {
                $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.splice(i, 1)
            }
        }
        save()
    }
}])
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="UserSettingsCtrl" ng-init="init()">

<div class="content">

    <header class="flex-container row header">
        <div class="flex-1">
            <h1 class="flex-1">{{ 'user_settings_title' | translate }}</h1>
        </div>
        <!--<a class="logout" href ui-sref="account.settings.changepassword">{{ 'user_change_password_menu' | translate }}</a>-->
    </header>

    <div class="main-edit">
        <div class="subsection">
            <div class="inputs-container-row full-width">
                <div class="input-group full-width">
                    <div class="inputfield">
                        <label class="label ng-binding" for="name">
                            {{ 'user_settings_firstname_label' | translate }}
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="userInfo.firstName" class="flex-1" ng-class="{'first-letter-to-upper' : userInfo.firstName.length > 0 }" placeholder="{{ 'user_settings_firstname_placeholder' | translate }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group full-width">
                    <div class="inputfield">
                        <label class="label ng-binding" for="name">
                            {{ 'user_settings_lastname_label' | translate }}
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="userInfo.lastName" class="flex-1" ng-class="{'first-letter-to-upper' : userInfo.lastName.length > 0 }" placeholder="{{ 'user_settings_lastname_placeholder' | translate }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputs-container-row full-width">
                <div class="inputs-container-row half-width">
                    <div class="input-group full-width">
                        <label class="label" for="name">{{ 'user_settings_language_label' | translate }}</label>
                        <div class="select-group full-width">
                            <select class="select" id="selectLanguage" ng-model="userInfo.language" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in availableLanguages"></select>
                            <label for="selectLanguage"><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs-container-row half-width">
                    <div class="input-group full-width">
                        <label class="label" for="name">
                            {{ 'user_settings_phone_label' | translate }}
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="userInfo.phoneNumber" placeholder="{{ 'user_settings_phone_placeholder' | translate }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subsection">
            <div class="inputs-container-row half-width">
                <div class="input-group full-width">
                    <label class="label" for="name">
                        {{ 'user_settings_password_label' | translate }}
                        <a ui-sref="account.settings.changepassword" class="button button-link--primary button--first">
                            {{ 'user_settings_password_button' | translate }}...
                        </a> 
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container row header">
        <div class="flex-1">
            <h1 class="flex-1">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_title' | translate }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--|||  Subscribe Start  |||-->
    <div class="main-edit">
        <div class="subsection">
            <div class="flex-container row">
                <div class="radiobutton-group">
                    <div class="width-140">
                        <input id="subscribed" type="checkbox" ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed" value="subscribed" class="radiobutton">
                        <label class="label highlight inline no-bottom-margin" for="subscribed">
                            {{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_subscribe' | translate }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed">
                <div class="flex-container row">
                    <div class="input-group flex-1" ng-switch="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription">
                        <label class="label" for="name">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_recurrence' | translate }}</label>
                        <div class="inputs-container-row half-width" name="oftenReportSent">
                            <span class="radiobutton flex-1" ng-class="{'checked' : analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'WeeklyAnalytics'}" name="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="WeeklyAnalytics" ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription" ng-change="updateSubscriptionType()" ng-checked="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'WeeklyAnalytics'" value="WeeklyAnalytics" id="WeeklyAnalytics" ng-required="">
                                <label for="WeeklyAnalytics">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_weekly' | translate }}</label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="radiobutton flex-1" ng-class="{'checked' : analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'MonthlyAnalytics'}">
                                <input type="radio" name="MonthlyAnalytics" ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription" ng-change="updateSubscriptionType()" ng-checked="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'MonthlyAnalytics'" value="MonthlyAnalytics" id="MonthlyAnalytics" ng-required="">
                                <label for="MonthlyAnalytics">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_monthly' | translate }}</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div> <span style="color:red;" ng-show="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription == null">Please select option</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1>Before</h1>
                <div ng-if="engines.length == 1">
                    <ul class="tags tags--inline item-with-inline-buttons">
                        <li ng-repeat="engine in engines | orderBy:'name'">
                            {{engine.name}}
                            <span class="button-icon button--primary button--delete" ng-click="removeSubscribedEngine(engine); selectFirstUnsubscribedEngine()">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h1>after</h1>
                <div ng-show="engines.length > 1">
                    <div class="flex-container row" ng-show="((engines | filter:{type:''}:true).length != 0)">
                        <div class="input-group full-width">
                            <label class="label" for="selectEngine">
                            {{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_engines_label' | translate }}:
                        </label>
                            <div class="half-width inputfield--horizontal" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <div class="full-width select-group" ng-if="(engines | filter:{type:''}:true).length > 0">

                                    <select class="select" id="selectEngine" ng-model="$parent.engine.current" ng-options="website.name for website in engines | filter:{type:''}:true | orderBy:'name'" ng-init="$parent.engine.current = (engines | filter:{type:''}:true | orderBy:'name')[0]">
                                </select>
                                    <label for="selectSubscription"><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <span ng-show="engines.length == 1">{{(engines | filter:{type:''}:true)[0].name}}</span>
                                <div id="btnAddWebSitesSubscription" ng-show="engines.length > 0" class="button button--add" ng-click="addSubscribedEngine(engine.current); selectFirstUnsubscribedEngine()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-model="successMessage" ng-show="showMessage" style="color:green;" class="message fadein fadeout">{{successMessage}}</div>
                </div>
                <h1 ng-show="subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length > 0 && engines.length > 1">Websites Subscribed</h1>
                <div class="flex-container row" ng-if="subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length > 0 && engines.length > 1">
                    <ul class="tags tags--inline item-with-inline-buttons">
                        <li ng-repeat="engine in engines | filter:{type:'Analytics'} | orderBy:'name'">
                            {{engine.name}}
                            <span class="button-icon button--primary button--delete" ng-click="removeSubscribedEngine(engine); selectFirstUnsubscribedEngine()">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="flex-container flex-end row footer">
            <button class="button button--primary button--action" ng-click="save();">
                    <i ng-show="loadingAction" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spinner-custom"></i>
                    <span ng-show="!loadingAction">{{ 'general_save' | translate }}</span>
            </button>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful of using ng-hide/ng-show as when the partial is 'hidden' it destroys the model (if there are any) contained within itself (so, use ng-if instead).

In your html in the subscription section, you make a call like this:

```
ng-change="updateSubscriptionType()"
```

But in your javascript you have:

```
$scope.updateSubscriptionType = function(engine) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
    updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine, $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription)
  }
}
```

So it's expecting an 'engine' argument, which you never pass in. But looking at the code you don't use the engine argument anyway; you use the 'engine' property of $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i] but that's it.

It however, doesn't do anything that I can see, anyway. It loops through an empty array then calls updatesubscriptions() to do something, but it won't actually call it.

Also, the updatesubscriptions() method itself doesn't actually do anything. This is probably why you're not getting anything in your array. I'd suggest modifying your template slightly, because the subscription radio buttons are outside the engines loop, so you won't be able to associate the subscription type with any engine. Once you have done that, then the subscriptions type radio buttons will have access to 'engine', which you can pass in. Modify your method accordingly:

```
$scope.updateSubscriptionType = function(engine) {
  if (!$scope.subscriptionEnginesFromService.includes(engine)) {
    $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromService.push(engine); 
  }
  updatesubscriptions(engine, $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription);
}
```

And also modify the updatesubscriptions() slightly.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. Could you tell me if I understand well; so you mean that I have to pass the engine in my Method populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(data)? So I have to change data or add engine? Can you give an example or tell me which method you think I should modify, please.

Comment: Hi @rrd Could you have any possibilities to answer me please I'm still stuck on this. I would like to understand where I have to pass that engine because I tried to pass in different methods and no success. Please provide me an example :) Thanks for help